# Attitude Era Bonus Match #1 Dude Love

Tags: wwe-13

For this bonus match, how do I complete the bonus objectives?

- Break a **normal table**?  I can only see the announce table and no others.
- Throw him through the barricade?  Where?  There are steel gates surrounding the ring but I can't seem to Irish Whip him through any of them.

Do these objectives become enabled later in the match?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You slam him on the steel railing and you have to take a table from under the ring apron.

Comment: How do you slam him through the barricade though?

Answer (score 2):

Irish Whip into a corner barricade when you have a F (finisher) icon, then when the "OMG" moment flashes up hit Triangle (PS3). It actually tells you this on the intro to the match...